# How to double click on image using appium

Tags: automation, appium, ui-automation

I have a requirement where I need to double click on an image to open it in Full-screen mode.

I have used below TouchActions class

```
TouchActions touchActions = new TouchActions(driver);
```

but I am facing below error

`The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasTouchScreen`

The type initializer for 'my class' threw an exception

Is there any way through which I can automate double tap on iOS device?

Comment: What driver are you using? How are you initializing your driver?

Comment: @econoMichael  I am using IOSDriver<IOSElement>

Comment: i think this may be because you imported the wrong touchactions. Selenium has their implementation as well as appium. make sure you are using appium's touch actions.

Comment: Can you pls help me with the correct references and example.. I am not able to find one

Comment: appium's implementation is actually called "TouchAction" (no "s"). From your code it's clear you have the wrong one. So remove this `import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;` and instead put in `import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;`

Comment: I am using C# as a language for development. Which nuget package would do help me?